# AJAX request not performed before page reload even with wait time

Tags: php, ajax, reload

POST EDIT: FYI, it turns out Firefox 48 was the issue. With Firefox 50 the code performs as intended.

We have some old code in our department that has a minor bug, but since I'm not very proficient with AJAX I have problems solving it.

The intended functionality is that the user clicks an element on the web page and this triggers a request that changes one number in a database. Then there is a wait time and then the page reloads. This is the relevant code performed in an onclick event:

```
request('../lib/ajax_lists.php','sideedit',data);
wait(500); //waiting until x ms passed
window.location.reload();
```

I checked these lines and they seem to work as intended, but not together.
What happens is that the browser waits, then reloads, but the database wasn't altered.
I then checked if the request function works and found out that the DB query was fine. But in order to see the query, which I printed to the request answer, I had to disable the reload. Now I could see the query, but to my surprise the database was changed also.

I did a few more tests and this is the result:

- The request including the database query in it isn't properly executed if
  the page reload function is enabled.
- If I comment out the reload function, the request is performed as intended, but of course without the needed reload to see the changes.
- Wait time doesn't seem to matter. I raised it to 5000ms but it still wasn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: It *is* old code. With AJAX you'd normall want to get the response from AJAX and update the page [without reloading.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: The browser tends to abort pending requests before a reload, perhaps this also causes the remote script to fail. [There's a setting in PHP that controlls this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: I understand that a reload wouldn't be necessary if it was designed differently, But a rewrite is out of the question.

I have to try that setting, but I'm still wondering why the request isn't executed properly even if there is more than enough time to do it.

Comment: I tried using ignore_user_abort(true), but it doesn't change anything. To me the whole behavior makes no sense. If I leave the reload in, it is like the request was never called. I added a error_log() output to the function that generates the DB query and with the reload t never shows up. Without the reload it does.

Comment: Why don't you use a callback and reload it there?

Comment: As I said in the original post, it's not my code and I didn't want to change it a lot because I have little experience with AJAX. Anyway, yesterday I added a comment in the original post. The problem isn't really the code, it seems, but Firefox. With a newer version, the code works as intended. It must've been a bug in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: But this would just reload the page regardless of user input and not after the user has clicked on the element and triggered the reload, right?

Comment: After 500 milliseconds after the page loads to be loaded again, users do not need the trigger. But need user trigger, code block in `$('button').click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }, 500);
});`